# Which part of JLS said anonymous classes cannot have public/protected/private member classes

Tags: java, inner-classes, access-modifiers, anonymous-class, jls

Consider this piece of code:

```
public class TopLevelClass {
    Cloneable c = new Cloneable() {
        private int privateField;
        private void privateMethod() {};
    };
}
```

There is an anonymous class that has a `private` member field and a `private` member method. It has been successfully compiled.

Then consider this one:

```
public class TopLevelClass {
    Cloneable c = new Cloneable() {
        private class PrivateInnerClass {}
    };
}
```

There is an anonymous class that has a `private` member class. However...

- javac said: `error: modifier private not allowed here`
- Eclipse said: `Illegal modifier for the local class PrivateInnerClass; only abstract or final is permitted` <sub>Really local class?</sub>

What? **Why anonymous classes cannot have `public`, `protected` or `private`<sub>(hereinafter referred to as `those`)</sub> member classes while they can have `those` member fields and methods?** Confused, I looked into JLS. Because of what Eclipse stated, I looked into [local classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3) first:

> ### 14.3. Local Class Declarations
>
> A *local class* is a nested class ([§8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)) that is not a member of any class and that has a name ([§6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2), [§6.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)).
> **It is a compile-time error if a local class declaration contains any of the access modifiers `public`, `protected`, or `private` ([§6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)), or the modifier `static` ([§8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)).**

So local class cannot have `those` modifiers. But `PrivateInnerClass` *is* a member of the anonymous `Cloneable`, so it is not a local class and is still able to have `those` modifiers.

Then I looked into [class modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1):

> #### 8.1.1. Class Modifiers
>
> The access modifier `public` ([§6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)) pertains only to top level classes ([§7.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)) and to member classes ([§8.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5)), not to local classes ([§14.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)) or anonymous classes ([§15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)).
> The access modifiers `protected` and `private` ([§6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)) pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration ([§8.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5)).

But `PrivateInnerClass` is a member class, and it's within a directly enclosing class, the anonymous `Cloneable`, so it can still have `those` modifiers on theory. I looked into other parts as well, but I still couldn't find relevant provisions.

***So which part of Java Language Specification said a member class of an anonymous class cannot have `those` modifier?***

---

**Extra Note 1:** Some answer argued about member classes and local classes, so I made a test that can conclude that (unless modifiers matters):

1. The anonymous `Cloneable` is **neither a member class nor a local class**.
2. The `PrivateInnerClass` is a member class, but **not a local class**.

The following is my test code:

```
public class TopLevelClass {
    Cloneable c = new Cloneable() {
        class PrivateInnerClass {}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> c1 = Class.forName("TopLevelClass$1");
        Class<?> c2 = Class.forName("TopLevelClass$1$PrivateInnerClass");
        System.out.println(c1.isMemberClass()); // false
        System.out.println(c1.isLocalClass()); // false
        System.out.println(c2.isMemberClass()); // true
        System.out.println(c2.isLocalClass()); // false
    }
}
```

---

**Extra Note 2:**
Review the declaration of a normal class ([JLS §8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)):

```
NormalClassDeclaration:
    ClassModifiersopt class Identifier TypeParametersopt
                                               Superopt Interfacesopt ClassBody
```

In my understanding, when the `Identifier` class is an XXX class, what [§8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) stated is restricting the modifier of `Identifier`, not the modifiers in other declarations in `ClassBody` of `Identifier`. Otherwise, anonymous classes even cannot have `those` member fields and methods.

**Any answer, especially which disagree with Extra Note 2, must point out why `those` member fields and methods are allowed.**

---

**Extra Note 3:** If you think there isn't such part of JLS, **you'll still need to give a reliable document to explain why `those` member classes are forbidden and why `those` member fields and methods are allowed.**

---

Comment: You have increased the convolution of your answer over time.

Comment: @JoshDM Half of it is to show my "research effort". Half of it is to tell answerers "I've found these fake proves, don't repeat it."

Answer (score 7):

You have:

1. Top-Level Class `TopLevelClass` : **not nested (hence is named, not local, not anonymous)**
2. Second-Level Class, a no-name class that extends `Clonable` and is a not a member of any class: **is anonymous (an inner class, is not a member, is in local scope but is not a 'local class')**
3. Third-Level Class `PrivateInnerClass`, a member of the anonymous class: **is nested, is not local, is not anonymous, is a non-static *inner class***

You are using the modifier `private` in (2).  Your included JLS text spells out this is illegal:

8.1.1

> The access modifier public (§6.6) pertains only to top level classes (§7.6) and to member classes (§8.5), **not to local classes** (§14.3) **or anonymous classes** (§15.9.5).
>   The access modifiers protected and private (§6.6) pertain **only to member classes** within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration (§8.5).

i.e. you can use none of these modifiers inside (in the scope of) an anonymous class.

---

Answer to Extra Note 2:

> ***In my understanding, when the Identifier class is an XXX class, what §8.1.1 stated is restricting the modifier of Identifier, not the modifiers in other declarations in ClassBody of Identifier. Otherwise, anonymous classes even cannot have those member fields and methods.***

1. Restriction of modifier before Identifier

   - This is spelled out in 8.1.1.  It clearly applies.
   - All modifiers can be applied before Identifier of a member class
   - `public` can be applied before top-level class Identifier
   - No modifiers can be applied before Identifier of local/anonymous classes (*classes declared in local scope*)

   Why is this?

   Because member classes can be referenced directly by other classes (through a 'member chain' from the top-level class), but **local/anonymous classes can never be referenced externally**.  Local/Anonymous class declarations are hidden in a scope that is itself not accessible to any other part of the java program.

   **Modifiers are *only* legal before a class declaration when the declaration is *accessible* to other classes.**
2. Restriction of modifier within ClassBody

   If a class Identifier/Declaration is not accessible to other parts of the java program, of course, the ClassBody is not accessible either.

   Hence, whenever a modifier is illegal before the Identifier, a modifier could have no possible semantic meaning within the ClassBody.

   **The rules for whether a modifier is allowed within ClassBody *must always be identical* to the rules for whether a modifier is allowed before Identifier**.
3. So 8.1.1. restricts modifiers in both places

:)

Comment: Please see my edit (Extra Note 2). There are too much words to put in a comment.

Comment: **1.** Any reference to JLS about the second paragraph? **2.** Why `those` member field and method are allowed? (Such as the code at the begin of my question) They are also inaccessible, aren't they?

Comment: 6.6: `Qualified names are a means of access to members of packages and reference types. When the name of such a member is classified from its context (§6.5.1) as a qualified type name (denoting a member of a package or reference type, §6.5.5.2) or a qualified expression name (denoting a member of a reference type, §6.5.6.2), access control is applied.`  6.6.1 `A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access`.

Comment: Re fields &methods: Agreed, they're inaccessible as well. Seems a compiler inconsistency. They should be covered by 6.6.

Comment: Of course, whether compiler allows access control modifiers next to inaccessible members is moot.  Whether or not the compiler allows such modifiers, there's no way at all the modifiers could have any effect.  Sorry to say, but it's futile to either specify them or worry why you can't. :)

Comment: But it didn't say `It is a compile-time error if something is accessible by nobody.` And if I think it's moot I won't ask this question.

Comment: Members such as those you've declared are inaccessible to other classes.  But they are accessible to the class in which they're declared.  Hence, it is legal to declare such members and not a compile error.  However, any modifiers to allow/restrict access to such members are impotent, because the members are already inaccessible externally - it is as if they were private without needing the access modifier *private*.  :)

Comment: Obviously it's nonsense to declare it as private (hence a warning). But which part of  **JLS** said it is a **compile-error**?

Comment: I believe that because it's nonsense, JLS has no need to cover it.  Makes no difference whether a compiler implementation rejects it as error (as per member class) or not (as per member fields/methods).  Both cases produce 100% working code with no artificial restrictions.  If the compiler covered every conceivable permutation that had no meaning it would bloat and become more impenetrable.  Often, the TCK (http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr901/index.html) picks up that level of  precise reproducable behaviour - not saying it does here, though.

Comment: Compilers must follow what JLS said. If JLS doesn't cover it, compiler shouldn't reject `those` member classes as error, at most giving a warning. Otherwise, there are no portability, and it's not Java.

Comment: Compilers must also pass the TCK - Test Compatability Kit.  This is used to give extra clarity/precision over JLS - especially behaviour for corner cases / in the margins.

Comment: You don't have to *like* what's in the JLS, but you do have to accept what is/isn't in there.  Sect 14.3 should really be applicable to Local *and Anonymous classes* - anything declared in a local scope (as I originally answered before you pulled me up on lack of name). But that text's not my fault.  I've answered your question with care & detail, pointed out what is/isn't in the JLS, and explained why accessiblility of your class gives your behaviour.  All correct, I believe.  Cheers :) :)

Comment: 1. Had we explain anything with "Because TCK", the *specification* can be deleted. 2. You said "private member methods are accessible to the class in which they're declared" 8 hours ago. But so is private member classes. 3. My requirement is "perfectly clear". Is "Makes no difference whether a compiler..." (1 hour ago) perfectly clear? (And there are no proof. You only hinted it is accepted that there may be no such part of JLS)

Comment: So you think the TCK could be a complete replacement for the JLS? (!)  I'll politely disagree. Also, I said both cases are inaccessible,  so whether or not modifiers are allowed, they could have never have any effect - either on external dependent classes or dependencies from within the anoymous class itself.  I Also said 14.3 *should* really apply to anonymous classes...  Thanks! :) :)

Comment: **You need to give a reliable document to explain why `those` member classes are forbidden and why `those` member fields and methods are allowed.** Now I only see your opinion. I never heard of TCK, how do I know if it really exists?

Comment: @GlenBest [Something you _might_ want to know about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188588/155556)

Comment: And *"The rules for whether a modifier is allowed within ClassBody must always be identical to the rules for whether a modifier is allowed before Identifier."* Please fix your statement, since you've approved that don't works for member fields and member methods.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the word 'contain'. PrivateInnerClass is a member of your anonymous class and it is contained within it, so it cannot itself have an access modifier, under rule 14.3.

It can have access modifiers for its *own* members, but you haven't explored that.

The Eclipse error message wrongly describes it as local.

You've also missed the point that 'private' would add nothing even if it were legal, as the inner class is invisible anyway.

Comment: §14.3: "*...if **a local class** declaration contains...*". Where is the local class? Neither the anonymous class nor `PrivateInnerClass` is a local class.

Answer (score 2):

My final answer consists of two thesis:

1. There is not strong declaration of restrictions for anonymous class members modifiers in the JLS. I.e. **there isn't such part of JLS**.
2. But according to JVM specs **anonymous** classes **aren't** members of class:

JVM 7 spec: **[4.7.6 The InnerClasses Attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6)** states:

> If C is not a member of a class or an interface (that is, if C is a
>   top-level class or interface (JLS §7.6) or a local class (JLS §14.3)
>   or an anonymous class (JLS §15.9.5))...

so, according to

**8.5 Member Type Declarations**

> A member class is a class whose declaration is directly enclosed in
>   another class or interface declaration.

*anonymous* classes **are not member classes**.

so, according to **8.1.1. Class Modifiers**:

> The access modifiers protected and private (§6.6) pertain only to
>   member classes within a directly enclosing class

**this classes aren't member classes, so they can not have mentioned modifiers**.

Comment: @johnchen902 Well, this is my final answer. You could agree or not. I have mentioned, that there isn't such part of JLS.

Comment: @johnchen902 any members of such classes can not have any mentioned modifiers

Comment: @johnchen902 What is my misunderstanding of §8.1.1?

Comment: @johnchen902 just to clarify I've updated my answer. Anonymous class is not member class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32946/discussion-between-andremoniy-and-johnchen902)

Comment: If you are still interested, please see my edit (Extra Note 2). There are too much words to put in a comment.